# How can I add an onclick event to a div that was created in the C# code behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, master-pages

Here I created an div in a loop (the div is populated with labels/data from my database):

```
    HtmlGenericControl availableTime =
    new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    availableTime.Attributes["id"] = "availableTime" + idCount.ToString();
    availableTime.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
    availableTime.Attributes["class"] = "availableTimeDiv";
    availableTime.Attributes.Add("onclick", "divClick()");
```

Here is the function I am trying to call:

```
    protected void divClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("CreateMeeting.aspx");
    }
```

The function never gets called, and the div isn't clickable.

Also, I need to get the id of the div and other elements within the div. Is a method call in the code behind the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I can provide you general example because you are not asking anything specific, but lets say this might looks like this:

```
_myButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm_delete();");

javascript:
function confirm_delete()
{
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the custom search by pressing button on div?")==true)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Bassically syntax goes like this:

```
div.Attributes.Add("onclick", DoSomething);
```

One more example :

```
Button divButton = new Button();
divButton.Attributes["style"] = "display:none;";
divButton.ID = "divBtn_" + id;
divButton.Text = id;
divButton.Click += divButton_Click;
```

div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return divclick();");

```
<script>
function divclick()
{
    var button = document.getElementById('divBtn_');
    button.click();

    return false;
}
</script>
```

I hope this is enought for you to understand how to attach click event on your div..